# Loading images from URL into gallery

Tags: android

I am trying to load images from a website into a gallery. The images fail to load into the gallery. The first (main) image does load.

```
    public class viewimages extends Activity {

private Gallery gallery;
private ImageView imgView;

private Integer[] Imgid = {
        R.drawable.a_1, R.drawable.a_2, R.drawable.a_3, R.drawable.a_4
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewimages);
    try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.mysite.com/images/1000298/pics/1.jpg");

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                            .getInputStream());
        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);    
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



     gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
     gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

     gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]); 
        }
    });


}

public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
    int GalItemBg;
    private Context cont;

    public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
        cont = c;

        TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        typArray.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Imgid.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);
        List<String> imageNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        imageNames.add("1.jpg");
        imageNames.add("2.jpg");
        //etc. until you've added all images

        for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.size(); i++){
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://www.mysite.com/images/1000298/pics/" + imageNames.get(i));
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                        .getInputStream());
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 70));
                imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }



        return imgView;
    }
}

    }
```

The problem seem to be in getView() in the AddImgAdp class. I am not sure if this is the correct place to attempt to load the images from a website?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first load all of the images. Basically what you're doing is when the adapter loads, you're then looping through, trying to load all the images. Create an async task that downloads your images (I would recommend just loading them into another arraylist until you get more comfortable with things like caching). Then, when you set the adapter, grab the position to use the image you're looking for. 
E.g.,

```
"imgView.setImageBitmap(imageArray.get(position))";
```

Answer (score 1):

Today already exists many android image loading libraries, try to use them to make development simpler. For example https://github.com/gobozov/Android-Universal-Image-Loader